# Unmarshalling root element returns null for sub elements

Tags: jaxb, xsd, unmarshalling

I am dealing with one weird issue from couple of days.  Issue is  with unmarshalling while getting values for root element.  All elements returned as null.

**Scenario:**  I have 2 XSDs with complex elements and with different namespaces  referred and imported in 3rd XSD.  JAXB files are generated in different packages.

If I use only simple XSD everything goes well. But referring sub elements from different XSDs returns null for sub elements after unmarshalling.

Answer (score 0):

Populate your object model and then marshal it to XML.  Then compare the XML that was marshalled to what you are unmarshalling to see where the problem might be.